# Can the plan cache be used to diagnose a lack of RAM?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory, monitoring, plan-cache

I have learned a few good ways to diagnose a lack of RAM on a SQL Server and I am wondering if I should add the plan cache to this toolbox.

A sign of lacking RAM is that the plan cache doesn't live very long. You can easily find the oldest cached plans in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` and you can find how much RAM the plan cache is using from `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks WHERE TYPE = 'CACHESTORE_SQLCP'`. **Can either of these be turned in to actionable information about your system lacking RAM?**

My suspicion is that neither view provides useful metrics. If 2% or 20% of my server's memory is taken up by the plan cache, then so what? Similarly, if my oldest cached plan is a month old, then so what? For all I know, it could just be a very frequently used plan.

Comment: In a vacuum, it's essentially meaningless unless you're specifically wanting to know the size of the plan cache.

Comment: It's really only telling you the turnover of the plan cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as **no** as far as plans can be invalidated by `Update Statistics` end `Index Rebuild`, for example on my server Index Rebuild/Update Statistics by Ola Hallengren (the code is smart enough to rebuild only those indexes that really need it) invalidates plans every night so that in the morning I have only few plans and in the afternoon the plan cache is large but it cannot give you any idea of my RAM.

This way you can measure your plans for every database, try to compare the results before and after rebuild/update statistics on busy OLTP server

```
SELECT db_name(st.dbid) as db,cp.objtype,
       cast(sum(cast (cp.size_in_bytes as bigint)) / 1024. / 1024 as numeric(10,2))as sizeMB,
       count(*) as cnt
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
--WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan'
      --AND cp.objtype IN ( N'Adhoc')
group by st.dbid, cp.objtype
ORDER BY sizeMB DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

And here you can see the causes of plan recompilation
[image]

Comment: I doubt this. I run regular maintenance and the oldest plan in my cache is about a month old.

Comment: @J.Mini it depends on how your data was changed, if the histogram is changed all the plans for queries using this objects are invalidated and even if you see the Plan old one month it only means that objects were not changed enough, try to measure your plan cache instead of seeking the oldest